# Nodejs and Expressjs: Constants in global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Defined in: util/constant.js**

```
module.exports = {
    userTypeAdmin: 0,
    userTypeUser: 1
};
```

**Required only once in: app.js**

```
...
global.constant = require('./util/constant');
...
```

**Used many times**

**In: route/index.js**

```
console.log(constant.userTypeAdmin); // Show 0
```

**In: route/user.js**

```
console.log(constant.userTypeUser); // Show 1
```

**Question:**

I must removed of **app.js**: `global.constant = require('./util/constant');`

and add: `const constant = require('../util/constant');`

in **route/index.js** and **route/user.js** ?
Or that's ok how I am it making?

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: Attaching properties to `global` object is not a good idea in general. Use `require` wherever you need it

Comment: I think it's ok if you want to use same constant file through entire application.but if you want to create separate constant file for you various module then your second way is good.(you can see your specific module constant in separate file)

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I have read that it is not a best practice to use global variables, so I asked if I should make the changes or not.

Comment: @ChandrakantThakkar I have only one file `util/constant.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.    const constant = require('../util/constant');
2.    global.constant = require('./util/constant');
```

Only difference in these,

statement 1 ask you to import the `constant` package wherever you want to use it.

statement 2  make available `constant` package globally.so,you can access it without import.

With statement 2,if you modified any properties within `constant`,it will reflect throughout the application.

*`So,make sure,you are using global only when you want to share something across the application.`*

If you want to share the data globally,and don't want this should be change,then delcare each primitive variable with `const` keyword.In this case,making object `const` will not help you.
  In either case you can exclude it.

Comment: I have read that it is not a best practice to use global variables, so I asked if I should make the changes or not.

Comment: @alditis `So,make sure,you are using global only when you want to share something across the application.` otherwise dont make it global

Comment: Well then I will keep the global variable even if it is a bad practice but neither is it a sacrilege and in this case it is necessary.